# Can Chrome extension name include Google product name?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can Chrome extension name include Google product name?

For example: "YouTube Hello"

Comment: Usually it's forbidden to use registered trademarks so I don't see why Google would allow that, but you can consult some place else where someone good in law is more likely to respond. Here this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your product is compatible with a Google product, make reference to that Google product by using the text "for", "for use with", or "compatible with", and be sure to include the ™ symbol with the Google trademark. Example: "for Google Chrome™"

Learn More

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/branding#description